# Cryptography with ASCII in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, ascii

I am trying to make a cryptography program.

When I run this program and insert for example `abc` with shift 2 it will return `cde` which is good. But I tried to insert `xyz` aswell with shift 3 and instead of shifting correctly `abc` it returns `aaa`. This also happens if I use shift 2 then it returns `zaa`.

How can I adjust my program to correctly start from the beginning when the alphabet is done with the ASCII tabel?

```
shift = int(input("Please insert a number you want to shift the characters with: "))

end = ""

for x in alf:
    ascii = ord(x)

if ascii >= 97 and ascii <= 122:
    res = ascii + shift
    if res > 122:
        res = 0 + 97
        min = res + shift
    end = end + chr(min)

print (end)
```

Comment: If `res` is bigger than 122 you set it to a fixed value of 97.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your logic expression is wrong. Here is an example that will allow any positive integer as right shift, beginning again at a again. And it can be very much optimized (hint: use modulo operator), but this is with minor changes to your code and numerics written out loud.

```
for x in alf:
  ascii = ord(x)

  if ascii >= 97 and ascii <= 122:
    res = ascii + shift
    while res > 122:
      res = res - (122 - 97) - 1
    end = end + chr(res)
```

Comment: Thank you very much stefan!